# How to show show if number ranges don't intersect with one another on SQL?

Tags: sql, numbers, range

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GAS_barcodeBatch]
(
    [idBarcodeBatch] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [barcodeIni] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [barcodeFin] [bigint] NOT NULL
)
```

with the following data:

```
idBarcodeBatch  barcodeIni  barcodeFin
19  3825027417017501    3825027417018000
20  3825027417011360    3825027417011500
21  3825027417017001    3825027417017500
22  3825027417031501    3825027417032500
23  3825027417017501    3825027417018500
```

the first column being the id, the other two being like the FROM and TO of number ranges.
In this example, what I need, is a query that shows me which batches intersect with one and other. Like the 19 and 23, those are intersecting each other with 500 records for instance.

So I would like to know if there is a way that I can show which batches are been affected by this process?

I've tried this one already, and it does return that result, however I'm not 100% convinced:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    GAS_barcodeBatch b1
    CROSS JOIN GAS_barcodeBatch b2 
WHERE 
    (
        b1.barcodeIni BETWEEN b2.barcodeIni AND b2.barcodeFin 
        OR b1.barcodeFin BETWEEN b2.barcodeIni AND b2.barcodeFin
    ) 
    AND b1.idBarcodeBatch <> b2.idBarcodeBatch
```

Regards

Comment: I often like to enumerate all of the possibilities when writing code for scenarios like this. In this case, you could quickly create a table (via pen or paper, or in a spreadsheet) and list all of the possibilities, e.g. `b1.barcodeFin < b2.barcodeIni`, `b1.barcodeFin = b2.barcodeIni`, `b1.barcodeFin > b2.barcodeIni`. That helps writing the correct code. Even better, you could use that table to write unit tests that you could run to be even more confident that your code is correct.

Comment: Also, is the value in `barcodeIni` *always* less than (or equal) to the value in `barcodeFin` for every row in the `dbo.GAS_barcodeBatch` table?

Comment: correct, ini will always be less than fin

Comment: Your code is fine by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a query to find overlapping ranges within this data like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   gas_barcodebatch b1
       JOIN gas_barcodebatch b2
          ON     b1.barcodeini <= b2.barcodefin
             AND b1.barcodefin >= b2.barcodeini
             AND b1.idBarcodeBatch <> b2.idBarcodeBatch
```

Strictly speaking, the result should be the same as your query. This one might perform somewhat better however, as SQL optimizers tend to do a better job with `and` than `or`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this?

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
    GAS_barcodeBatch where barcodeIni in
    (
      select barcodeIni from GAS_barcodeBatch
      group by barcodeIni
      having count(barcodeIni)>1
     );
```